# Yoga Laptop - Autodisable Keyboard when screen folded back to use as tablet? (Help with possible fix)

Tags: keyboard, lenovo

I have a [Yoga 530-14IKB Laptop (ideapad) - Type 81EK](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-530-14ikb/81ek/81ek007nau/pf122un7/documentation/doc_userguide) @lenovo.com and it has a feature where you can fold the laptop backward and turn the laptop into a pad. This works very well in windows as it disables the physical keyboard.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the touch screen is working fine.. the only problem is that it is not automatically disabling when I fold the monitor backwards.

I would probably disable it manually with a terminal command and then enable it again in such a way, but there must be a sensor as it is automatic in windows 10 and I would love to find a way to do this in linux as well.

I found this script [Tablet mode detection and setup scripts for linux](https://github.com/alesguzik/linux_detect_tablet_mode) @GitHub but I can not work out how it is supposed to work...

I installed ruby ( sudo apt install ruby )

Than I copied the two files form the page... the settings file and the script.

The instructions say...

1. Install ruby and stdbuf (most likely you already have them preinstalled)
2. Clone it somewhere, and optionally symlink watch_tablet into any directory in your $PATH
3. Copy a config file into ~/.config/watch_tablet.yml
4. Adjust the config (see below)
5. Add watch_tablet & to your ~/.xinitrc
   6.Restart your desktop session and enjoy

I did everything but (2).. I do not know what that means.

The config instructions say...

> input_device is a path to the device that provides the tablet mode
> switch. To find it you may run [I]stdbuf -oL libinput
> debug-events|grep switch[/I] and notice something like event4 in the
> leftmost column. That would correspond to /dev/input/event4. Device
> numbers may be unstable across reboots, so you may consider doing ls
> -lh /dev/input/by-path and finding a symlink to that device. For X1 Yoga Gen2 it's /dev/input/by-path/platform-thinkpad_acpi-event.
>
> modes.laptop, modes.tablet - this contain commands that will be
> executed when mode changes. Most likely this will contain xinput
> enable and xinput disable commands to enable/disable
> kb/touchpad/trackpoint (just run xinput to look them up). You may use
> any other commands to adjust your desktop environment (e.g. hide or
> show additional panels, increase button size, hide/show onscreen
> keyboard etc.)

But the command "*stdbuf -oL libinput debug-events|grep switch*" dose not work?

> :~$ stdbuf -oL libinput debug-events|grep switch stdbuf: failed to run
> command ‘libinput’: No such file or directory

Anyone know how I can get this working or know a method to turn off the keyboard when the Yoga is folded backward?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install `libinput-tools` in order to get the actual `libinput` command. At the command line run:

```
sudo apt install libinput-tools
```

After doing this, that long command should run. In case it wasn't clear, you're supposed to run that command (which will just hang around waiting for something to happen) and then fold your Yoga into tablet mode and back - this will cause the waiting command to print out the event info that corresponds to tablet_mode.